# Renomear ImageView para Upload

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, processamento-de-imagens

Bom dia,

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida, meu APP até o momento o cara tira uma foto do celular e fica numa ImageView (Ex: img1), preciso que seja criado um nome definido por mim numa variável exemplo: 04102018_Foto1.jpg, teria alguma forma para que eu possa enviar ao BD com esse nome definido por mim ?

Code:

```
  String dataAtualFormatada = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(System.currentTimeMillis());


    btnTirarFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent((MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            //  Toast.makeText(TelaAtestado.this, "Atestado cadastrado com sucesso! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Comprimir Imagem = PNG/JPG ----- QUALITY:
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo, você apenas está pegando o thumb da imagem, o que acho que no seu caso não seria o melhor caso.

Para poder salvar a imagem real da camera, é necessário criar um arquivo e mandar o endereço para ele.

(Metodo para criar o arquivo temporario)

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */ 
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Guarda o endereço da imagem (para utilizar no imageview, por exemplo)
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Metodo para chamar a camera

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Verifica se existe uma camera para abrir
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Cria o arquivo para salvar a imagem
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Erro criando o arquivo
        }
        // Caso o arquivo seja criado, é chamada a camera
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Com isso, podemos pegar no File retornado no `createImageFile()` e copiar ele para o caminho desejado, e com o nome desejado (após salvar) usando o metodo

`FileUtils.copyFile(File origem, File dest);`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, estarei testando e dando tudo certo dou um retorno !

Comment: Estou com uma dúvida, se eu quiser passar ela junto com as outras Strings pra enviar via Json como faria ex:                                        
                String contrato = txtContrato.getText().toString();
                String data = txtHorario.getText().toString();
                String observacoes = txtObservacao.getText().toString();